# Javascript - How to return object with promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to return an object with a specific structure but i can't return the object.

As you can see in the code if i print inside promise it prints data but if i print outside is empty... why?

How can i return the object parts?

```
var parts = [];
var part = [];
var articles = [];

part.push(request.query("SELECT u_order, u_familia, u_part, u_type FROM u_part (nolock) where u_order <'92' and u_order <> '100'"));

return Promise.all([Promise.all(part)]).then(function(listOfResults)
{
  for(var i=0; i<listOfResults[0][0].length; i++)
  {
    articles.push(request.query("SELECT st.u_posic, sc.ref, sc.qtt, sc.design FROM st INNER JOIN sc ON st.ref = sc.ref where sc.ststamp ='"+stamp+"' and st.u_posic = '"+listOfResults[0][0][i].u_order+"'"));
    //articles.push(request.query("SELECT ststamp, ref, design FROM st (nolock) WHERE u_posic = '"+listOfResults[0][0][i].u_order+"'"));

    Promise.all([Promise.all(articles)]).then(function(listOfArticles)
    {

      for(var j=0; j<listOfResults[0][0].length; j++)
      {
        parts.push({
          u_order: listOfResults[0][0][j].u_order,
          u_familia: listOfResults[0][0][j].u_familia,
          u_part: listOfResults[0][0][j].u_part,
          u_type: listOfResults[0][0][j].u_type,
          articles: listOfArticles[0][j-1]
        });

        console.log(parts); HERE THE OBJECT HAD DATA
      }


    });

  }
  console.log(parts); BUT HERE IS EMPTY

}).catch(function(err)
{
    console.log(err);
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why the nested `Promise.all` call ? If you want to return an object, you should add a `Promise.resolve()` call and maybe chain a `.then()` method in your nested `Promise.all()` call

Comment: `Promise.all([Promise.all(part)])` what does this suppose to do?

Answer (score 3):

The whole point of `Promises` is being asynchronous. You need to wait for your Promise to `resolve` or `reject` to check for data. Specifically, you should only do anything with the returned value of your `Promise` within the `Promise.then()` method, which runs as soon as the `Promise` finishes execution. Changing variables which exist *outside* the `Promise` from within it, as you are doing by calling `parts.push()` is a bad practice. You should `return parts` within your promise, and then, in a final `.then()` callback, you should do whatever is required with `parts`.

Something like:

```
Promise.all(part).then(makeAllQueries).then(doSomethingWithQueryResults);
```

You can only be sure you actually *have* data or not when your final `.then` callback runs.

Also, doing `Promise.all([Promise.all(part)])` does nothing for you, as you're just wrapping your returned array in one more array level.

Comment: Can you help me use better promises and the better my code given what I want? I do not know how to use promises very well. @PedroCastilho

Comment: You should check the reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) out.

The whole idea of a `Promise` is that you don't know when it will finish running. So you can't do something within a promise (in _asynchronous_ code) and try to access that value from _synchronous_ code (code which runs outside that Promise). That's why you have a `.then` callback - so that you can be sure you have the data _within that callback_. You should then notify any parts of your program that need the data _from the callback_.